# How do I record my phone conversations on this phone?

Tags: iphone

How do I record my conversations on this phone?

Comment: Please try to provide a little more information – at least it would be useful to know what phone and what OS you are using. Otherwise: a.f.a.i.k. recording conversations without the other person knowing is at least in some countries quite illegal.

Comment: Take a look at this page at [Digital Trends](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-record-calls-iphone/2/).

Comment: @tillinberlin It is legal in many others so this is on topic and should be answered

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to record phone calls on an iPhone primarily due to the dubious legality of recording calls in most countries without someone's permission. However if your phone is jailbroken (not recommended) there are 3rd party apps.

Alternatively you could look at using a cable to record from the headphone jack to a dictaphone or on speaker.